# Simple operations on every element in numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a newbie at numpy, but I was of that notion that you should not iterate over numpy arrays as this defies the purpose of numpy.

I'm trying to perform elementwise operations on a numpy array, but I don't understand the syntax apparantly:

**Code:**

```
for line in fidNNC:
    temp = line.strip().split()
    temp.insert(0,0)
    CC.append(temp[0:7])

fidNNC.close()
NNC = np.array(CC)
del(CC)

inds = np.arange(len(NNC))[ NNC[:,4]-1 == NNC[:,1] ]
NNCX = NNC[inds,:]
inds = np.arange(len(NNC))[ NNC[:,5]-1 == NNC[:,2] ]
NNCY = NNC[inds,:]
```

The file `fidNNC` contains about a million rows and ten columns of ints.

**Error message:**

```
    inds = np.arange(len(NNC))[ NNC[:,4]-1 == NNC[:,1] ]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'int'
```

How do I subtract 1 from each and every one element of `NNC[:,4]` and `NNC[:,5]` without iterating?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: Ahh, I should read that question/answer closely, looked similar to my problem. NNC.dtype = |S3

Comment: Which I was guessing after looking at your code again :) I removed the comment and added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not converting to `int` when reading the file, thus the created array has the string type. Convert to `int` and it should work:

```
for line in fidNNC:
    temp = [int(i) for i in line.strip().split()]
    temp.insert(0,0)
    CC.append(temp[0:7])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deconstruct the matrix by column and perform operations on the columns you like and re-create, np.c_ allows this.  For example a matrix x we can subtract 1 from the first column like so (and place result in z)

```
z = np.c_[ (x[:,1] - 1), x[:,1:] ]
```

This pulls out the first column on x, elementwise subtraction on that column and concatenates the rest of the untouched columns.  To do two columns simply break up further